# How to list ftp directory through html

Tags: ftp, file-transfer, html, hosting, directory-listing

So i finally got a brazilian free hosting provider to host my files but when i type the my URL in the browser it says "PAGE NOT FOUND". Id need to edit/create a "index.html". But thats not what i want, i just want it to display the directory from my ftp which is bound to that subdomain, but it doesnt. Tried using .htaccess but no success. Is there a script code in html so that the browser will show all the files from the ftp directory and make it possible for download (just like .htaccess)?

I would like it to look like this:

anyone types in my domain: user.xpg.com.br/files

and all the files and folders i had uploaded to the ftp server would simply show up available for download.

script must be in html, server does not allow php or sql or c+

Hosting service provider:

http://xpg.uol.com.br/

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Have you tried to start URL with `ftp://`? Most browser automatically generate the listing page.

Comment: Yes it opens in ftp ://name:pass@ftp.xpg.com.br, but i need to be able to view it in http ://user.xpg.com/files (dont mind spaces between ftp&http)